# Selenium / Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

I have this error  `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="channel-icon-wrapper-2eYxZ"]"}`

Here is the code
`connexion_bar = driver.find_element_by_name("channel-icon-wrapper-2eYxZ")`

And here is the code HTML `<div class="channel-name-2qzLW">Utiliser téléphone/e-mail/nom d'utilisateur</div>`

I try to replace `connexion_bar = driver.find_element_by_name("channel-icon-wrapper-2eYxZ")` by `connexion_bar = driver.find_element_by_class_name("channel-icon-wrapper-2eYxZ")` but there is the same error message :/

Comment: Why do you insist on searching for `channel-icon-wrapper-2eYxZ` either by name or by class when your HTML does not even contain that string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class attribute seems dynamic.To identify the element use either of the following options

**Xpath**:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'channel-name-')]")
```

OR

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()='Utiliser téléphone/e-mail/nom d'utilisateur']")
```

OR **Css selector**

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[class^='channel-name']")
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks for your help !